# I can’t open terminal by clicking terminal icon

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, icons, themes

I don’t know what happen to my terminal. When I double click the terminal icon to make the terminal and the only thing happens is the cursor spinning forever. What is the problem with it? How to fix it? I think it also prevent me from using GNOME Tweaks to change my theme.

I can only open it with other ways such right click desktop and choose “open terminal”. By clicking it to open will cause the spinner to spin forever.

Comment: can you open it by Ctr+Alt+T?

Comment: I just realized that I can't event use Ctrl + Alt + T to open the terminal. So far I can do is to right click on desktop and select "Open Terminal"

Comment: try entering `gnome-terminal` in terminal (you can open by right-clicking desktop ryt). does it open a new terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I will have to do some digging, but for now, you can use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open up the terminal, let me know know that works.

Comment: I was wondering what happen to the system. It opens with different ways beside clicking it.

Comment: have you tried restarting your pc/desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot attest as to what the cause is, but a sure way to bring up your terminal is to ctrl+alt+T.
Alternatively, you can click the applications button - if you haven't disabled it - and find and launch it from there.  From there you can also add a new shortcut to your dash by right clicking and "Adding to Favourites".
Hope this helped.  Please keep us informed.